# Why do we prove that $x \ne y$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Theorem. A set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is open if and only if its complement $A'=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}:x \notin A\}$ is closed.
>
> Proof. Assume $A$ is open. Let $\{x_{k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence in $A'$ with limit $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Let $y \in A$. We want to show $x \ne y$.
>
> For $y \in A$, by $A$ being open, there is $r>0$ such that $B_{r}(y) \subset A$. By $x_{k} \notin A$, we know $x_{k} \notin B_{r}(y)$, so $\Vert x_{k}-y \Vert \ge r$ and thus by convergence of $\{x_{k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$, for $\epsilon = \dfrac{r}{2}$ there is $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for each $k \ge N$, $\Vert x_{k}-x \Vert < \epsilon =\dfrac{r}{2}$, so
>
> $\Vert x-y \Vert = \Vert x-x_{k}+x_{k}-y\Vert \ge \big\vert \Vert x_{k}-y \Vert - \Vert x-x_{k} \Vert \big\vert > \dfrac{r}{2} \ne 0$. Thus $x \notin A$, or equivalently, $x \in A'$, meaning $A$ contains its limit points, so it's closed.

I was wondering why it's important to show that $x \ne y$? If we suppose that $x \in A$, then $A$ open implies that there is some $\epsilon$ such that $(x-\epsilon, x+ \epsilon)$ is completely contained in $A$. Hence $x_{k}\in (x-\epsilon, x+ \epsilon) \subset A$ for $k \ge N$, a contradiction.

Comment: How do you define a closed subset of $\Bbb R$? It is often defined as the complement of an open one.

Comment: it seems like you do know why it's important to show that $x \not = y$, but you just have an easier proof in mind of one direction of the theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $y\in A$ by showing $y\ne x$ we show that $x\in A'$ which makes $A'$ closed